# How to show (algebraically) the C-vM statistic is a special case of general form of Anderson-Darling

Tags: statistical-significance, goodness-of-fit, anderson-darling-test

Anderson and Darling proposed the GoF $n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[F_{emp}(x)-F(x)]^2 \phi (F(x)) \; dF(x)$ where $\phi (F(x))$ is a weight function. How can I obtain Cramer-von Mises statistic $CM=\frac{1}{12n}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(z_i -\frac{2i-1}{2n})^2$ by considering $\phi (F(x))=1$?

Comment: When you say "obtain" are you talking about taking a value computed on data and convert from one to the other, or are you talking about algebraically showing that the C-vM statistic is a special case of that general form of Anderson-Darling?

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you so much for the comment. I mean how to obtain  the C-vM statistic as a special case of the general form of Anderson-Darling algebraically.

Comment: The Anderson-Darling (AD) statistic and Cramer-von Mises (CvM) statistic are both quadratic EDF statistics. The AD has form

$$A_{n}^{2}=n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(F_{n}(x)-F(x))^2}{F(x)(1-F(x))}dF(x)$$

and the CvM has form

$$W_{n}^{2}=n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(F_{n}(x)-F(x))^2dF(x)$$

If we consider your notation, then for the AD the weight function would be

$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-x)}$$

That should be enough to understand the relationship between the two statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Anderson-Darling (AD) statistic and Cramer-von Mises (CvM) statistic are both quadratic EDF statistics. The AD has form
$$A_{n}^{2}=n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(F_{n}(x)-F(x))^2}{F(x)(1-F(x))}dF(x)$$
and the CvM has form
$$W_{n}^{2}=n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(F_{n}(x)-F(x))^2dF(x)$$
If we consider your notation, then for the AD the weight function would be
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-x)}$$
That should be enough to understand the relationship between the two statistics.

Comment: I understood it well. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.